# Node.js express force client to skip cache (refresh)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, caching

I'm sending a file in node.js / express like this:

```
res.header("Content-Type", mime.lookup(file));
res.sendFile(file);
```

On sever side I can detect if that file has changed and I want to force client to skip cache only in that case.

something like:

```
res.header("Content-Type", mime.lookup(file));
if (fileHasChanged(file))
  res.header("some-header-telling-client-to-skip-cache", "some-value");
res.sendFile(file);
```

How can I do that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag

Comment: That's very helpful thanks! Unfortunately express sets automatically ETag header and override mine... :(

Comment: @lviggiani Express sets the ETag based on the file contents, so if the file changes, the ETag changes too and _in theory_ the client should reload the resource. Are you using a proxy in front of Express? Can you see if the client is sending an `If-None-Match` request header?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like, you need to add `'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'` to you the sendFile() options:

```
const options = {
  headers: {
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  }
};

res.sendFile(file, options, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    next(err);
  } else {
    // Success
  }
});
```